# Adding PHP to a Magento Block or Magento Page

Tags: php, blocks, page

I am new to Magento and have been reading all of the answers on how to add PHP to a Magento block or page.  Seems that just adding  doesn't work.  I have seen answers like this

```
{{block type="core/template" name="my_distributors_block" template="page/distributors.phtml"}}
```

My challenge is trying to determine where to put the **phtml** file.  I have tried putting it in a php directory off of root directory of the server like:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="**php/test.phtml**"}}
```

If I just want to add custom php

1. What are the exact steps
2. Is there any documentation that describes what each attribute means, that is what is `type`, what is `name` and what is `template`

Where does **phtml** files need to reside?  Working with Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all `core/template` is not a part of Magento 2.

Answers.

- To add any phtml file you need a block or layout file to define a path of your phtml file.
- `type` is use to define your Block class which is connected to your
  phtml file. So you can access block methods in your phtml file.
- `name` is used to set a name of your block. It must be unique.
- `template` is used to define your phtml file. You have to add template path.

  **phtml** files are available on module level and on theme level too. you can find those file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates` and `app/design/frontend/packageName/themename/Vendor_Module/templates`

Comment: Rakesh, Thank you for getting back.  Is there a good document that describes what I need to do in order to run customer php code in a page or block?

I have placed the below code in the /app/code/SMCH/ManReg/view/frontend/templates

<?php echo "Here I am!!!!"; ?>

<h1>
<BR>
HTML Text
</h1>

How would I access this from a page or a block?

Comment: I am looking to add php code to page, possibly have it render html tabs that php may print out for display on the page.  Is there documentation for this?

Comment: check this link https://www.rakeshvarma.com/magento2/create-block-and-phtml-in-magento-2/ hope it will helpful.